# Using PARSE REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parse-platform

I am currently stuck on a task in which I have to use jQuery ajax to retrieve messages from PARSE HERE API to create something like this:

http://chatbuilder.hackreactor.com/?example=1&username=aa

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me how to use REST api to retrieve messages.

I have looked at other people's coding examples:

https://github.com/stevernator/Chatbuilder/blob/master/draft11

and

https://gist.github.com/guymorita/5726564

They seem to use ajax code like below:

```
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            var stuff = [];
            for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
              stuff[i] = data.results[i].text 
            }
```

My question is: from where are the messages being generated from in this app? Do I have to create an account at Parse or would I just use ajax to retrieve this url link:"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats"?

Also, where would I find info on this specific class (chats)? 
Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you understand what Parse does. The chat message objects are both created and retrieved through the Parse API, and they're specific to your particular account and project. Parse is a way of storing objects for your application: you're not using it to retrieve other people's chats or anything like that.

Comment: Ah I see. That clarifies things a lot. So this requires me to learn Parse to create an object containing the messages then I would have to link this API to my application, correct? Do you recommend the Quick Start Guide for JavaScript or Windows? Or how can I learn this API quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parse quick start guide is a very good place to start. The documentation is really good but the tutorials for the JS API are far more complex (backbone) than the documentation. I would download the Todos tutorial as there is some good stuff in it but if you dont know how backbone works its harder to read. I would have made this a comment but I don't have enough rep :(.